# PHP Curl blocked by Cloudflare but not if use Fiddler Proxy

Tags: php, curl

why php curl blocked but not blocked if I use Fiddler proxy (there are no special setup), it is because carriage return `\n vs \r\n` or curl certificate?

without fiddler I Got response

```
<title>Please Wait... | Cloudflare</title>
```

and with Fiddle proxy enabled

```
<title>Subscene - Passionate about good subtitles</title>
```

and the script

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888'); // uncomment to enable fiddler proxy
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://subscene.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo $html;
```

Comment: Looks like the site is using Cloudflare's DDOS or bot protection, and fiddler is somehow using a header that does not trigger it.

Comment: Grab a webserver and do the requests to it from both clients, that way you will see the differences. Alternatively, use packet sniffing.

Comment: running on hawkhost still have the problem, another strange results that if I use python `requests` it blocked but not if using `cloudscraper`. clouscraper do nothing because first response not contain `Please Wait... | Cloudflare`

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @mike you need to make request using valid version number of certificate